# Schedule task 10 minutes after install

Tags: scheduled-apex, postinstall

I have a schedulable class in my package that would run every hour to pull data using a callout and put it in the custom object.

I am aware of using system.schedule as below:

`String scheduleTime='0 '+currentMinute+' '+currentHour+' '+currentMonth+' '+currentYear+' ?'`

`system.schedule('MyJob', scheduleTime, new SchedulableC(context.installerId()));`

I was wondering if there is a better way to run the job only ONCE after install.

Comment: quick 'n dirty: unschedule the job when it runs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wait a month, there is a new method in Summer '13 which does exactly this.

> The new ***System.scheduleBatch*** method is handy for scheduling a batch job to run once at a future time. The only
>   prerequisite is creating your batch class that implements the Database.Batchable interface. You don’t need to deal with
>   the scheduling details, such as implementing the Schedulable interface or constructing a time and date (CronTrigger)
>   expression.

Check the Summer 13 release notes for more details https://na1.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/salesforce_summer13_release_notes.pdf

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion :) But I can not wait for that long so I guess I will implement it so that job runs only once, since I am not allowed to make a callout oninstall.